# Trying to implement jstl in jsp from List

Tags: java, jsp

Here is my Java code :

```
   List<EmployeeBean>questionList=adao.displayQuestions(eBean,functional_id);
   model.addObject("questionList", questionList);

   Iterator<EmployeeBean> iterator = questionList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       String q_id =iterator.next().getSk_question_id();
       System.out.println("QUESTION ID :"+q_id);
       List<EmployeeBean>optionList= adao.displayOptions(eBean,q_id);
       model.addObject("optionList", optionList);
      }
```

String q_id will have mutiple id's based on the first list (questionList).
Based on q_id, I will get multiple options from second list (optionList).

Here is what I am trying in jsp:
I am not able to get optionList values. getting only last values of the list

```
  <c:forEach var="EmployeeBean" items="${questionList}">
   ${EmployeeBean.question_name }

     <c:forEach var="EmployeeBean" items="${optionList}">
       <div class="col-xs-4 starategy-data">
       <div class="strategy-head">${EmployeeBean.answer_type }</div>
       <p>${EmployeeBean.answer }</p>
       </div>
     </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: what is your question then ?

Comment: I am not able to get optionList values. getting only last values of the list

Comment: you are setting the optionList attribute anew every iteration in the while loop. meaning that you are replacing it.. that is one error.

Comment: How to overcome this issue. I am new to this. Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way(it may not show correct,if one `q_id` not has related data list):

```
   List<EmployeeBean>questionList=adao.displayQuestions(eBean,functional_id);
   model.addObject("questionList", questionList);

   List<List<EmployeeBean>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
   Iterator<EmployeeBean> iterator = questionList.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          String q_id = iterator.next().getSk_question_id();
          System.out.println("QUESTION ID :"+q_id);
          resultList.add(adao.displayOptions(eBean,q_id));//store it by index
   }
   model.addObject("optionList", resultList);
```

JSP code:

```
 <c:forEach var="EmployeeBean" items="${questionList}" varStatus="status">
   ${EmployeeBean.question_name }

     <c:forEach var="EmployeeBean" items="${optionList.get(status.index)}"><!-- get the related data list -->
       <div class="col-xs-4 starategy-data">
       <div class="strategy-head">${EmployeeBean.answer_type }</div>
       <p>${EmployeeBean.answer }</p>
       </div>
     </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
```

---

Another way(I have not try,you can test)

Java code:

```
   List<EmployeeBean>questionList=adao.displayQuestions(eBean,functional_id);
   model.addObject("questionList", questionList);

   int index = 0;
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          String q_id = iterator.next().getSk_question_id();
          System.out.println("QUESTION ID :"+q_id);
          model.addObject("optionList_"+index,adao.displayOptions(eBean,q_id));
          index++;
   }
```

JSP code:

```
<c:forEach var="EmployeeBean" items="${questionList}" varStatus="status">
   ${EmployeeBean.question_name }

     <c:forEach var="EmployeeBean" items="${optionList_status.index}"><!-- not sure if it can work correct here -->
       <div class="col-xs-4 starategy-data">
       <div class="strategy-head">${EmployeeBean.answer_type }</div>
       <p>${EmployeeBean.answer }</p>
       </div>
     </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Tried this, got this exception : javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;

Comment: @Manju For the first answer,I am not sure if one of the `q_id` do not have data list,then if it works fine(it will add an empty list).You need test your self.

Comment: Yeah, I have tested it on my end it works fine. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   List<EmployeeBean>questionList=adao.displayQuestions(eBean,functional_id);
   model.addObject("questionList", questionList);


   List<EmployeeBean>optionList = new ArrayList<>();
   Iterator<EmployeeBean> iterator = questionList.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          String q_id =iterator.next().getSk_question_id();
          System.out.println("QUESTION ID :"+q_id);
          optionList.addAll(adao.displayOptions(eBean,q_id)); 
   }
   model.addObject("optionList", optionList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Only getting first values of optionList now! for every q_id same values are repeating.

Comment: By the way, avoid _ and use camel-case rule instead (q_id --> qId)

Comment: Thanks for the answer